# Anaconda Windows: certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda

I have python 3.10 bundled in my anaconda installation in Windows. Tried running this block of code in jupyter notebook:

```
daft = Daft()
listings = daft.search(max_pages=1)

for listing in listings:
   print(listing.title)
   print(listing.price)
   print(listing.daft_link)
```

But I got this error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gateway.[web address]', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /old/v1/listings (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

How can I resolve this please? Thanks!